# i m stuck in upload image on firebase cloud firestore. Can anyone help me .?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
const { user_id, username } = this.props;
const { imagePath } = this.state;

const fileExtension = imagePath.split(".").pop();
console.log("EXT: " + fileExtension);

var uuid = uuidv4();

const fileName = `${uuid}.${fileExtension}`;
console.log("fiile name ---> " + fileName);

this.setState({ profile_image : fileName });
```

And

```
export const addManualContact = 
    (username, profile_image ) => {
         firebase.firestore().collection('user').doc(`${username}`).collection('contacts').add({ profile_image: profile_image }) }
```

Comment: Nothing here uploads a file to Firebase. Did you try anything already? If not, I recommend starting with the documentation.

Comment: yes, i edited in my question .

Comment: What do you expect this code to do now? And what does it do instead?

Comment: i need to upload image on cloud firestore . and download and show in another screen . So Please help me how to upload image on " Cloud firestore " and how to download and show image......

Comment: Is [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-upload-files-to-firebase-cloud-storage-with-react-and-node-js-e87d80aeded1) what you are looking for?

Comment: I Find this solution Thank you all of you

Comment: @krunalraval Could you post your solution as an answer so that other in the community can refer to it in case they go face the same issue and accept this? This will also help you raise your reputation in SO.

Comment: @RafaelLemos yes i post and answer ..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my library `import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-crop-picker";`

Here is function:

```
//Here is take photo from gallery 
 takePhotoFromCamera2 = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
    }).then((image2) => {
      this.setState({ profile_image2: image.path });
      console.log(image2);
      this.setState({
        image2: {
          uri: image2.path,
          width: image2.width,
          height: image2.height,
          mime: image2.mime,
        },
        images: null,
      });
    });
  };
```

and I upload the image in Firestore like this:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection("user")
        .doc(`${username}`)
        .update({ profile_image: profile_image });
```